# C# - Get the sum of the total amount of width for each column in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, sum, width

Is there any faster way other than looping through each column and increment a variable with their width?

For now this is the best solution, but is pretty slow:

```
int contentWidth = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in grid.Columns) {
    contentWidth += column.Width;
}
```

Comment: and why you downvote my answer?

Comment: @KamikyIT I didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the length of visible columns:

```
contentWidth = grid.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.Displayed);
```